# Standard byte sizes for variables in C?

Tags: c, variables, memory, stdint

So, I was writing an implementation of ye olde SHA1 algorithm in C (I know it's insecure, it's for the Matasano problems), and for some of the variables it's pretty crucial that they're exactly 32 bits long. Having read that `unsigned long int` is 32 bits by standard, I just used that, and then spent 4 hours trying to find why the hell my hashes were coming out all wrong, until I thought to see what `sizeof(unsigned long int)` came out to be. Spoiler, it was 64.

Now of course I'm using `uint32_t`, and always will in the future, but could someone (preferably, someone who has more discretion and less gullibility than I do) please point me to where the *actual* standards for variable sizes are written down for modern C? Or tell me why this question is misguided, if it is?

Comment: The *actual* place will be the standard, and it and all respectable tutorials and references say that sizes are platform dependent. That's why the `[u]intxx_t` types were added.

Comment: The standard says that long int will be as big as or bigger than int, and tries very hard to avoid being too specific.  The standard is the wrong place to look for the answer you seek.

Comment: On page 27 of the standard which I found here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf, it says:

Maximum value for an object of type `unsigned long int`: 2**32 - 1.

Which seems pretty specific to me, and so I am still not sure what to believe...

Comment: OK, one page above that, it says "Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown," so that explains that. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **minimum** sizes are:

- `char` - 8-bit
- `short` - 16-bit
- `int` - 16-bit
- `long` - 32-bit
- `long long` - 64-bit

There are no maximum sizes, the compiler writer chooses whatever they think will work best for the target platform.  The corresponding unsigned types have the same minimum size.

Comment: Well, I should say, I believe you, even though as far as I can tell the standard declares that the *maximum* value of an unsigned long int is 2^32 - 1. But I'm probably looking at the wrong page or something...

Comment: @gmoss the standard doesn't say that

Comment: OK, I found the phrase "Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown." Section 5.2.4.2.1, numbered pages 26-27 (pdf pages 45-46) of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf. Thanks for your very quick help!